# problem using option fleqn in amsmath package

Tags: amsmath, align, indentation

I'm using the following code. What should I do if I don't want the fixed indent from the left margin of my page?
‎

```
\documentclass[‎fleqn,oneside‎]{article}‎
‎\usepackage{amsmath}‎
....
\begin{align}
a_1& =b_1+c_1\\
a_2& =b_2+c_2-d_2+e_2
\end{align}
```

Comment: Special case of [Align equation left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145657/250119), covered in some part of the corresponding answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set the length `\mathindent` to zero:

```
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
```

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: you can regulate that distance by setting `\mathindent` (to 0pt, for example), with a `\setlength\mathindent{<value>}`

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\hrulefill

\begin{align}
a_1 &= b_1+c_1\\
a_2 &= b_2+c_2-d_2+e_2
\end{align}

\setlength\mathindent{0pt}
\hrulefill

\begin{align}
a_1 &= b_1+c_1\\
a_2 &= b_2+c_2-d_2+e_2
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Using Thorsten's method affects the math indent for the whole page. If that's not what you want I would suggest using the nccmath package for fleqn like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent This is text on the page here.\\
\begin{fleqn}[0pt]
\begin{align*}
a_1 &= b_1+c_1 \\
a_2 &= b_2+c_2-d_2+e_2\\
\end{align*}
\end{fleqn}
This is more text on the page down here.\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: Be careful using the `nccmath` package as I have had several problems using it. See [this question for a list of them](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22170/is-there-a-replacement-for-nccmath)

Answer (score 7):

Just to make this complete (I found an easy answer only after a lengthy search):
the standard length of `\mathindent` (in KoMa **scrbook** class) is `<\leftmargini minus \leftmargini>`. The rubber part is essential for longer equations.

Answer (score 3):

You have to determine the length `\mathindent`. See code below for an example.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength{\mathindent}{\parindent}

\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    a_1 &= b_1+c_1 \\
    a_2 &= b_2+c_2-d_2+e_2
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```