# Positioning of equations

Tags: math-mode, positioning

How would I shift my whole set of equations/calculations at the left, to be aligned with "Example"?

[image]

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,epsfig,epstopdf,titling,url,array}
\usepackage{parskip}


\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter] % reset theorem numbering for each chapter
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem*{cor}{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition} % definition numbers are dependent on theorem numbers
\newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Example} % same for example numbers
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{rem}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{note}{Note}


\title{My Thesis Title}
\author{My Name}
\date{\today}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{(\theenumi)}
\renewcommand\theenumi{\roman{enumi}}
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Addition}

\begin{exmp} 
Here is an example.
\begin{align} \nonumber
(a+b)^3 &= (a+b)^2(a+b)\\ \nonumber
&=(a^2+2ab+b^2)(a+b)\\ \nonumber
&=(a^3+2a^2b+ab^2) + (a^2b+2ab^2+b^3)\\ \nonumber
&=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3 \nonumber
\end{align}
\end{exmp}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The first problem I see is that you are using the `align` environment which centers automatically the equation.

Comment: Check this post [problem using option fleqn in amsmath package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8740/10898)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this line:

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,epsfig,epstopdf,titling,url,array}
```

To these:

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,epsfig,epstopdf,titling,url,array}
```

> Strictly speaking, the `amsmath` package doesn't use `\mathindent` to
>   control the left indent of displayed equations when the fleqn option
>   is in effect: it uses an internal parameter `\@mathmargin` instead.
>   However, for compatibility with existing LaTeX documentation,
>   `amsmath` turns `\mathindent` into an alias for `\@mathmargin`. There
>   is a small risk here: In the plain LaTeX implementation, `\mathindent`
>   is a dimen register, but with amsmath `\@mathmargin` is a skip
>   register and, by association, so is `\mathindent`. If any package or
>   documentclass uses `\mathindent` in a way that depends on it being a
>   dimen register, when used in conjunction with the `amsmath` package it
>   may be vulnerable to a well-known pitfall having to do with the
>   primitive TeX lookahead for a plus or minus key word. However if the
>   standard LaTeX commands `\setlength` and `\addtolength` are used to
>   modify `\mathindent` then this problem will not arise.

The above can be found at [Technical notes on the amsmath package](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/technote.pdf).

Comment: This works if I change $$...$$ to \\[ ... \\]