# Positioning of equations (begin equation command)

Tags: positioning

This is a follow up from my previous question, 
[Positioning of equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50233/positioning-of-equations). I managed to get my equations alligned to the left, but in my latex document, I have also been using:

```
\begin{equation}
X^2 := x^2 - 123. \nonumber
\end{equation}
```

I have alot of other equations that I want to be centered. For example, for all my equations wrapped around:

```
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}
```

How would I center it? Thanks, my code is below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,epsfig,epstopdf,titling,url,array}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter] % reset theorem numbering for each chapter
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem*{cor}{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition} % definition numbers are dependent on theorem numbers
\newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Example} % same for example numbers
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{rem}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{note}{Note}


\title{My Thesis Title}
\author{My Name}
\date{\today}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{(\theenumi)}
\renewcommand\theenumi{\roman{enumi}}
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Addition}

\begin{exmp} 
Here is an example.
\begin{align} \nonumber
(a+b)^3 &= (a+b)^2(a+b)\\ \nonumber
&=(a^2+2ab+b^2)(a+b)\\ \nonumber
&=(a^3+2a^2b+ab^2) + (a^2b+2ab^2+b^3)\\ \nonumber
&=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3 \nonumber
\end{align}
\end{exmp}

\begin{exmp}
A simple equation:
\begin{equation}
X^2 := x^2 - 123. \nonumber
\end{equation}
\end{exmp}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why should some equations go centered and other left aligned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more general solution is to load the `nccmath` package and wrap each equation you want flush-left in a `fleqn` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{fleqn}
    \begin{align*}
    a&=b\\
    &=c
    \end{align*}
\end{fleqn}
Which implies
    \begin{equation}
    a=c
    \end{equation}
But
\begin{fleqn}
    \[ 0\ne 5 \]
And
    \[ 2\ne 3 \]
\end{fleqn}
\end{document}
```

If `nccmath` causes problems, you could also define `fleqn` like this:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment*{fleqn}{
    \@fleqntrue
    \setlength\@mathmargin{0pt}%
    \ignorespaces
}{%
    \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thansk so much, really appreciate it rdhs!

Comment: If you are considering using `nccmath` please do have a look at [Is there a replacement for nccmath?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22170/is-there-a-replacement-for-nccmath).

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using the `[fleqn]` option which is a global option, leave the default centering behaviour but use `flalign` rather than `align` environment when you want flush left alignment.

Comment: I was about to say the same thing. :-)

Comment: How would I use the flalign command in my case?

Comment: @Gary write `\begin{flalign}` and `\end{flalign}` instead of the usual `align` environments. `flalign` probably has a starred version as well.