# How to align arrays?

Tags: arrays

What would be the easiest way to align the following block to the left?

```
\[ \left.
\begin{array}{l}
\text{Wenn A eintritt, tritt auch B ein.} \\
\text{Aus A folgt B.} \\
\text{A impliziert B.} \\
\text{A ist hinreichend für B.} \\
\text{A ist hinreichende Bedingung für B.}
\end{array}
\right\} A \Rightarrow B \]
```

Comment: ...to the left margin of the text block?

Comment: Exactly, so it's in line with the rest of the page.

Comment: Then it's a duplicate of: [Positioning of equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50233/5764)