# Indentation of left-aligned equations (flalign) without fleqn

Tags: math-mode, equations, indentation

I would like to have some math not centered but left aligned. So I found on this site various answers that pointed me to this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
1+1=2  &&
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

However I also would like the left aligned math to be indented by `\parindent`, how could I do that without loading `fleqn` as a general option?

Comment: Is there any reason for not using the option `fleqn`?

Comment: @Ch'enMeng because only some math should be left aligned, not all.

Comment: @BeeGirl Well, try `$ ... $` with `\displaystyle` (if really need)?

Comment: @Ch'enMeng but that doesn't work for multiline math? Despite my example I need this for multiline equations.

Comment: @BeeGirl `aligned` environment, provided by `amsmath`, works well in inline-math. And its syntax is familiar with `align` and `split` who are used to typeset multiline equations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [problem using option fleqn in amsmath package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8740/problem-using-option-fleqn-in-amsmath-package)

Comment: @HenriMenke that is not the same issue since the OP is using fleqn, while I said I don't want to

Comment: @Ch'enMeng thanks, `aligned` seems to be almost it. Is it possible to control the indent amount of an `aligned` env and set it to `\parindent`?

Comment: @BeeGirl The environment `aligned` is often used as a part of a certain equaion (or maybe the whole part), say block-env. Hence, the answer is no. :(

Comment: @Closers this question is different from the one linked as a duplicate since here the OP wants both centered and left-aligned equations.

Comment: Just to be picky: `flalign` ***doesn't*** mean “left aligned equations”, but “full length align”. Having some display centered and others left aligned doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Remarks

You can indent your `flalign` by using the definition of `flalign`from `amsmath.sty` and modifiying it to your liking, e.g. inserting `\hskip\parindent`.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty} % for cropping
\newcommand\shortlipsum{
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
    vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
    mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.\par
} % Filltext
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{shiftedflalign}{%
    \start@align\tw@\st@rredfalse\m@ne%
    \hskip\parindent
}{%
    \endalign
}
\newenvironment{shiftedflalign*}{%
    \start@align\tw@\st@rredtrue\m@ne
    \hskip\parindent
}{%
    \endalign
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\shortlipsum
\begin{flalign}
    1+1=2  &&
\end{flalign}
\shortlipsum
\moveright\parindent\vbox{%
\begin{flalign}
    1+1=2  &&
\end{flalign}
}
\shortlipsum
\begin{shiftedflalign}
    1+1=2  &&
\end{shiftedflalign}
\shortlipsum

\begin{flalign*}
    1+1=2  &&
\end{flalign*}
\shortlipsum
\begin{shiftedflalign*}
    1+1=2  &&
\end{shiftedflalign*}
\shortlipsum

\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: ok, this is it. Could you point out to a question that describes the differences between the various math environments? Also a resource online, not necessarily on this site. Thanks

Comment: @BeeGirl The [`mathmode`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) manual by Herbert Voß describes all the important things.

Comment: @HenriMenke Can you remove the superfluous `%` in `\newenvironment{shiftedflalign}`? It caused me to question why that was not in `\newenvironment{shiftedflalign*}`.

Comment: As an aside, you can use `\mathindent` (see [LaTeX/Advanced Mathematics](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Indented_Equations)) instead of `\parindent` to get the normal indentation used by `fleqn`.

Answer (score 12):

A very simple method.

We define a new command

```
\newcommand{\mathleft}{\@fleqntrue\@mathmargin\parindent}
```

to simulate the option `fleqn` with `\parindent` indenting, and a new command to restore the normal behavior

```
\newcommand{\mathcenter}{\@fleqnfalse}
```

So, add the following lines in the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathleft}{\@fleqntrue\@mathmargin\parindent}
\newcommand{\mathcenter}{\@fleqnfalse}
\makeatother
```

and issue `\mathleft` before and `\mathcenter` after the math stuff you want left aligned with `\parindent`.

You can use this solution with all math environments without redefining any of them.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathleft}{\@fleqntrue\@mathmargin\parindent}
\newcommand{\mathcenter}{\@fleqnfalse}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mathleft
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
\mathcenter

Indented paragraph

\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}

Indented paragraph

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: this is not really safe, the `fleqn` option is a mixture of load-time and run-time changes and changing the value of the boolean flag after the package is loaded leaves amsmath in a broken state, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462885