# Equation numbering does not continue correctly in Latex

Tags: math-mode, equations, numbering

In my thesis, I have a problem when I want to refer to equations. Reference is basically happening based on section or subsections numbering in three digits (e.g. 1-1-1). Also, if I have more than one equation in the same subsection, all are shown by the same number! (1.1.2 in the following example!)! The number beside each equation is correctly shown, however, as (1-1) or (1-2) or ... . I want the equation number in the text be shown sequentially as 1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 
... .

Please help me solve this problem. Thanks

---

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,english,singlespacing,parskip,headsepline]{MastersDoctoralThesis}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathleft}{\@fleqntrue\@mathmargin0pt}
\newcommand{\mathcenter}{\@fleqnfalse}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section1}
\subsection{Subsection 1-1}

\mathleft
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:KE_Energy}
\begin{aligned}
& \langle KE \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \langle mv^{2} \rangle \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Equation \ref{eq:KE_Energy} is kinetic energy.

\subsection{Subsection 1-2}

\mathleft
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:KE_Energy2}
\begin{aligned}
& \langle KE \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \langle mv^{2} \rangle \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Equation \ref{eq:KE_Energy2} is kinetic energy.

\mathleft
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:KE_Energy3}
\begin{aligned}
& \langle KE \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \langle mv^{2} \rangle \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Equation \ref{eq:KE_Energy3} is kinetic energy.

\section{Section2}
\subsection{Subsection 2-1}

\mathleft
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:KE_Energy4}
\begin{aligned}
& \langle KE \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \langle mv^{2} \rangle \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Equation \ref{eq:KE_Energy4} is kinetic energy.

\end{document}
```

An here is the output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that can be used by others to replicate your problem.

Comment: The equation numbering in LaTeX is always correct. It's your configuration that is incorrect. In this example you do not need the `aligned` environment. If you include a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) we can tell you how to fix your configuration.

Comment: I would expect that your `\mathleft` and `\mathcenter` commands break `amsmath`, where did you find those definitions?

Comment: @mah65, I believe the problem might be with your .cls file. I compiled your MWE exactly as you gave it except I used the `book` document class instead of your custom class file, and I was unable to replicate your problem. When I compiled with the `book` class, the `\ref` and `\label` numbering for the equations matched.

Comment: @MasonMalone: Thanks for your help. That is correct, although the hyperlink to equation is ruined. Anyways, I have to use thesis style, and should solve the problem in this environment. I don't know what modification I should apply in the .cls file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I removed \newcommand{\mathcenter}{\@fleqnfalse}. It did not solve the problem.

Comment: @Raven ....... I added MWE.

Comment: @Andrew ....... I added MWE.

Comment: you still have `\mathleft`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the previous answer, I modified the packages as following:

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathleft}{\@fleqntrue\@mathmargin0pt}
\newcommand{\mathcenter}{\@fleqnfalse}
\makeatother
\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}
```

(Changes are the first and last lines).
This solved the problem, and no other modification is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The `\mathleft` and `\mathcenter` commands defined in the preamble break `amsmath` removing all use of them restores the correct numbering.

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,english,singlespacing,parskip,headsepline]{MastersDoctoralThesis}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
%\newcommand{\mathleft}{\@fleqntrue\@mathmargin0pt}
%\newcommand{\mathcenter}{\@fleqnfalse}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section1}
\subsection{Subsection 1-1}

%\mathleft
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:KE_Energy}
\begin{aligned}
& \langle KE \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \langle mv^{2} \rangle \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Equation \ref{eq:KE_Energy} is kinetic energy.

\subsection{Subsection 1-2}

%\mathleft
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:KE_Energy2}
\begin{aligned}
& \langle KE \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \langle mv^{2} \rangle \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Equation \ref{eq:KE_Energy2} is kinetic energy.

%\mathleft
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:KE_Energy3}
\begin{aligned}
& \langle KE \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \langle mv^{2} \rangle \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Equation \ref{eq:KE_Energy3} is kinetic energy.

\section{Section2}
\subsection{Subsection 2-1}

%\mathleft
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:KE_Energy4}
\begin{aligned}
& \langle KE \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \langle mv^{2} \rangle \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Equation \ref{eq:KE_Energy4} is kinetic energy.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to work. But this brings all the equations to the middle (centring). How to keep them in the left side?

Comment: @mah65 use the documented `fleqn` option to the documentclass or to amsmath or mathtools package

Comment: @mah65 did you write this `\mathleft` command or was it suggested in some tutorial somewhere?

Comment: I think I found it somewhere in this forum when I wanted to align left the equations. I don't exactly remember.

Comment: @mah65 well it's completely wrong, so if you recall where it came from try to ping the author to get it changed:-)

Comment: Probably, here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148838/indentation-of-left-aligned-equations-flalign-without-fleqn