# Left alignment of equation

Tags: horizontal-alignment

How can I left align these equations below?

```
\begin{subequations}\label{BC:main}
Acrescido das condições de contorno: 
\begin{equation}
p(r,\theta=\pm \pi, t > 0)=0 \label{BC:p}
\end{equation}
Para expressar que o corpo está circundado pelo próprio fluido.
\begin{equation}
p(r\rightarrow\infty, \theta, t>0)=\frac{K_{1}}{\sqrt{2\pi r}}\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})  \label{BC:pp}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{T}_{\alpha\beta}(r\rightarrow\infty,\theta,t>0)=\frac{K_{1}}{\sqrt{2\pi r}}[f_{\alpha\beta}(\theta)-\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})\mathbf{I}]+p\mathbf{I}      \label{BC:t}
\end{equation}
Para reforçar que o material é incompressível a determinada distância da ponta da trinca (equações \eqref{BC:pp} e \eqref{BC:t}).
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{T}_{22}(r,\theta\pm \pi,t>0)=\mathbf{T}_{12}(r,\theta\pm \pi,t>0)=0      \label{BC:tt}
\end{equation}
Para reforçar a condição que a superfície da trinca é livre de tensões.
\end{subequations}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: check [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8740/]

Comment: Align doesn’t work for one single equation:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&p(r,\theta=\pm \pi, t > 0)=0 \label{BC:p}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

And if I put it below \begin{subequations} it returns error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want? I took the liberty to load `cleveref`, as it saves quite some typing for cross-references.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, brazilian]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{BC:main}
  Acrescido das condições de contorno:
  \begin{align}
     & p(r,\theta=±\pi, t > 0)=0 \label{BC:p} \\
    \intertext{Para expressar que o corpo está circundado pelo próprio fluido.}
     & p(r → ∞, \theta, t>0)=\frac{K_{1}}{√{2πr}}\cos\Bigl(\frac{θ}{2}\Bigr) \label{BC:pp} \\
     & \mathbf{T}_{αβ}(r → ∞,\theta,t>0)=\frac{K_{1}}{√{2πr}}\biggl[f_{αβ}(θ)-\cos\Bigl(\frac{θ}{2}\Bigr)\mathbf{I}\biggr]+p\mathbf{I} \label{BC:t} \\
    \intertext{Para reforçar que o material é incompressível a determinada distância da ponta da trinca (\cref{BC:pp,BC:t}).}
     & \mathbf{T}_{22}(r,θ±\pi,t>0)=\mathbf{T}_{12}(r,θ±\pi,t>0)=0 \label{BC:tt}
  \end{align}
  Para reforçar a condição que a superfície da trinca é livre de tensões.
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I needed. Many thanks!