# How to align math expressions and texts

Tags: align

In fact, I want to have the fourth expression (T_v) aligned in the left as the previous ones and also I want to have a good align design in the second case where there is speed on point, mean speed and noise

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
With:\\ \\
$m_1$= 0.4 . \\
$m_2$= 0.25 .\\
$K_f$= $\sqrt{2T_v(1-m_{2}^2)(\frac{m_1^2}{m_2^2}-m_2+1-m_1^2)^{-1}}$ . \\
\[T_v= \frac{L_v}{V_{moy}}\]
\\ \\ \\
With:\\ \\
$V_{0}$\textit{(t,$\omega$)}: Speed on point $V_0$.\\
$V_{mea}$: Mean speed.\\
B\textit{(t,$\omega$)}: Noise.\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: you should almost never use `\\ ` outside of tables and alignments and certainly never do `\\ \\ `  which generates `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)` which is the _maximum_ measure of badness that TeX assigns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that employs two `array` environments. All material is snugged up against the left-hand edge of the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\newcolumntype{m}{>{\displaystyle}l}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\noindent
With:\\[1ex]
$\begin{array}{@{} m @{{}={}} m }
m_1 & 0.4  \\
m_2 & 0.25 \\
K_f & \Bigl[2T_v(1-m_{2}^2)\Bigl(\frac{m_1^2}{m_2^2}
      -m_2+1-m_1^2 \Bigr)^{\!\!-1}\, \Bigr]^{1/2} \\
T_v & \frac{L_v}{V_{\mathrm{moy}}}
\end{array}$

\bigskip\noindent
With:\\[1ex]
$\begin{array}{@{}mL}
V_{0}(t,\omega)  & Speed on point $V_0$\\
V_{\mathrm{mea}} & Mean speed\\
B(t,\omega)      & Noise
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I really do not fully understand what you want to achieve, but I am wondering if the following goes in the right direction.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
With:
\begin{align*}
m_1&= 0.4 . \\
m_2&= 0.25 .\\
K_f&= \sqrt{2T_v(1-m_{2}^2)\left(\frac{m_1^2}{m_2^2}-m_2+1-m_1^2\right)^{-1}} . \\
T_v&= \frac{L_v}{V_\mathrm{moy}}
\end{align*}
With:
\begin{align*}
V_{0}(t,\omega)&:~\text{Speed on point $V_0$}.\\
V_\mathrm{mea}&:~\text{Mean speed}.\\
B(t,\omega)&:~\text{Noise}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: If you want to move the equations to the left, use

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt} % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8744/121799
\begin{document}
\noindent
With:
\begin{align*}
m_1&= 0.4 . \\
m_2&= 0.25 .\\
K_f&= \sqrt{2T_v(1-m_{2}^2)\left(\frac{m_1^2}{m_2^2}-m_2+1-m_1^2\right)^{-1}} . \\
T_v&= \frac{L_v}{V_\mathrm{moy}}
\end{align*}
With:
\begin{align*}
V_{0}(t,\omega)&:~\text{Speed on point $V_0$}.\\
V_\mathrm{mea}&:~\text{Mean speed}.\\
B(t,\omega)&:~\text{Noise}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And if you want the alignment anchor to be on the left, use

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\noindent
With:
\begin{align*}
&m_1= 0.4 . \\
&m_2= 0.25 .\\
&K_f= \sqrt{2T_v(1-m_{2}^2)\left(\frac{m_1^2}{m_2^2}-m_2+1-m_1^2\right)^{-1}} . \\
&T_v= \frac{L_v}{V_\mathrm{moy}}
\end{align*}
With:
\begin{align*}
&V_{0}(t,\omega):~\text{Speed on point $V_0$}.\\
&V_\mathrm{mea}:~\text{Mean speed}.\\
&B(t,\omega):~\text{Noise}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

None of these options look too nice to me, but this is a matter of taste.

Comment: Yes that's what I want but I want them to be aligned on the left

Comment: In fact it's not working for me, I don't know why when I use  \setlength{\mathindent}{0pt} and run latex it says  ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. Do you have a better representation of that

Comment: @twimo Sorry, I can't reproduce your statement. These snippets run without an error. I have double-checked this with pdflatex, xelatex and lualatex.

Answer (score 0):

You can align using  `flalign*` and `\shortintertext` (from `mathtools` ). For the second alignment, I prefer a `description` environment, with style `nextline`, and a tabular environment with a vertical rule on the left, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
\shortintertext{With:}
   & m_1= 0.4 . & \\
   & m_2= 0.25. \\
   & K_f = \sqrt{2T_v(1-m_{2}^2)\biggl(\frac{m_1^2}{m_2^2}-m_2+1-m_1^2\biggr)^{\!-1}}. \\
   & T_v= \frac{L_v}{V_\text{moy}} .
\end{flalign*}

\begin{description}[style = nextline, font = \mdseries, leftmargin = 0.5em]
\item[With\medskip]
\begin{tabular}{|>{$}l <{$} l}
V_{0}(t, \omega): & Speed on point $V_0$.\\
V_\text{mea}: & Mean speed.\\
B(t,\omega): & Noise.
\end{tabular}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]