# How can I align all my mhchem v4 reactions in LaTeX to the left of the page rather than have them centred

Tags: align, alignment, mhchem

so i have a whole bunch of reactions that i want to align to the left of the page rather than in the center, now it looks like this:
[image: centred reaction].

I do still need the reactions to be numbered

So I would like it to look like this:

[image]

the code snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-acs]{biblatex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item The photo-excitation of CQ from ground state to singlet state
    \begin{equation}
    \ce{CQ <=>[kigs][kisg] CQ(s)^*}
    \label{CQ excitation}
    \end{equation}
    \item The ISC from singlet CQ to triplet CQ
    \begin{equation}
    \ce{CQ(s)^* <=>[kist][kits] CQ(t)^*}
    \label{CQ ISC}
    \end{equation}  
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

where [\kigs][\kisg] are the rates.
I have already tried \begin{align} using & but this only aligns it to other reactions and not to the page

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please always paste a small, but complete and compilable document to your question, so that others can easily reproduce your output.

Comment: I hope this is better?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8743/226 should help, i.e. add `fleqn` to your `\documentclass` options and `\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}` after `amsmath`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Bernards answer did the trick for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to left align equations only in this context, here are two possible alignments, with the `fleqn` environment, from `nccmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc, enumitem}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-acs]{biblatex}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\newlength{\bwd}
\settowidth{\bwd}{\textbullet}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item The photo-excitation of CQ from ground state to singlet state
\begin{fleqn}
    \begin{equation}
    \ce{CQ <=>[kigs][kisg] CQ(s)^*}
    \label{CQ excitation}
    \end{equation}
\end{fleqn}
    \item The ISC from singlet CQ to triplet CQ
\begin{fleqn}[-\dimexpr\labelsep + \bwd]
    \begin{equation}
    \ce{CQ(s)^* <=>[kist][kits] CQ(t)^*}
    \label{CQ ISC}
    \end{equation}
\end{fleqn}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, that was exactly what i wanted